# Powerapps, if statement getting warnings

Tags: powerapps

I'm new to powerapps and having issue with an if statment with multiple conditions for a list box that is dependent on a dropdown with two variables, I keep getting an error:

> Warning: The columns produced by this rule are all nested tables
>   and\or records, however the property expects at least some columns of
>   simple values (such as text, or numbers).

These are the variables:

Listbox1_1 is used for filtering and contains the selection.

Dropdown4 contains 'Yes' or 'No'.

Reason_table_1 is a table with 3 columns: 'Reason for Visit', 'if Yes', 'if No'.

This is my code for the if statment:

```
If(
    Dropdown4.SelectedText.Value="Yes",Filter(Reason_Table_1, 'Reason for Visit' in ListBox1_1.SelectedItems.Result).'if YES',
    Dropdown4.SelectedText.Value="No", Filter(Reason_Table_1, 'Reason for Visit' in ListBox1_1.SelectedItems.Result).'if no')
```

I'm sure my if statement is wrong but not sure where.
any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think below line is the issue,

> Reason_table_1 is a table with 3 columns: 'Reason for Visit', 'if
>   Yes', 'if No'.

Do you mean for your table Reason_table_1 you have 3 columns and you would like to set column 'if Yes' or column 'if No' depending on your condition?

If this is the case, Then it is not possible.

Reason for your Listbox you are trying to set different columns based on your condition and not different values on only 1 column. This is not possible

It should not be like below image

[image]

Rather it should be like this.
[image]

[Here is the nice Thred. Read through it and you will get the issue.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Using-one-Drop-Down-selection-fill-another-drop-down/td-p/18481)